# PythonでSyntaxError: can't assign to function callが出てしまい困っています。

Tags: python3

最近,大学でPythonの勉強を始めて本当に間もない者です.
大学の講義で以下のようなプログラムがあり,
実行しようとしてみたところエラーが出てしまいました.
資料がかすれて見づらいこともあるのですが,
自分では何が間違っているのか分からず困っています.
また,最終的にはグラフを表示させるプログラムであることはわかるのですが
各行のコードの意味もよくわかっていません.
できれば,そちらについても教えていただけると幸いです.

・コード

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import matpoltlib.pyplot as plt
def f(x):
        return 2*np.sin(x)-(x**2)/8.0

print("x=0:",f(0.0),"x=4",f(4.0))
x_array=np.zeros(3)
y_array=np.zeros(3)
x_array(0)=0
x_array(1)=1
x_array(2)=2

x=np.linspace(0,10,20)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,f(x))
plt.title(r'f(x)=2sin(x)-x*x/8')
plt.xlabel(r'x')
plt.ylabel(r'f(x)')
plt.scatter(x_array,y_array)

#plt.savefig('lec9.png')
plt.show()
```

・エラー

```
参考コード1.py", line 11
    x_array(0)=0
            ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Answer (score 1):

お疲れ様です。
以下、３つコメントします。

（１）
x_array[0]（　(0) が、まずい。）が正解かと思います。

（２）
pythonのエラーメッセージは、適切だったと記憶しています。
functionじゃないと指摘しています。

（３）
matplotのスペルが間違っています。
手元ではそこをそれも修正したら、実行できました。

以上